# Refresh mat datasource from other component or service in angular 7

Tags: angular, reactjs, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have 2 component namely project and project-list and then project service.
The project.component.ts has form to submit and project.list1.component.ts displays the list of projects.

When I submit project form in project.component.ts, I would to like refresh project.list1.component listData which is MatDatasourcetable. I tried to call service methods refreshList() or getProjectList() from project.component.ts after submit form but it is not refreshing **listData**. Also I have injected ***ChangeDetectorRef*** as suggested by others but this also does not refresh matdatasource. Something i am missing to figure out. Whenever I submit/update  immediately the projectlist must refresh show updated list records.

**project.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewChild, ElementRef, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/shared/project.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
import { ProjectModel } from 'src/app/shared/project.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/users/user.service';
import { User } from 'src/app/users/user.model';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project',
  templateUrl: './project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project.component.css']
})
export class ProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ProjectService,private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,private toastr: ToastrService, private userService: UserService) { }

    isValidDate: any;
    error:any={isError:false,errorMessage:''};
    minDate: Date;
    IsChecked:boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm(); 
  }
  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form != null)
      form.resetForm();
    this.service.formData = {
      ProjectID: null,
      ProjectName: '',
      StartDate:null ,
      EndDate:null              
    }         
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {    
      if (form.value.ProjectID == null)    
        this.insertRecord(form);
      else
        this.updateRecord(form);   
  }

  insertRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.postProject(form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.toastr.success('Inserted successfully', 'Project. Register');
      this.resetForm(form);
      //this.service.refreshList(); 
      //this.service.getProjectList();
    });
   this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }

  updateRecord(form: NgForm) {
    this.service.putProject(form.value).subscribe(res => {
      this.toastr.info('Updated successfully', 'Project. Register');
      this.resetForm(form);
      //this.service.refreshList();
      //this.service.getProjectList();           
    });
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }   
}
```

**project-list1.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostBinding } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from 'src/app/shared/project.service';
import { MatTableDataSource,MatSort,MatPaginator } from '@angular/material';
import { ProjectModel } from 'src/app/shared/project.model';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-list1',
  templateUrl: './project-list1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-list1.component.css']
})
export class ProjectList1Component implements OnInit {

  constructor(private service: ProjectService,
    private toastr: ToastrService) { }     

  listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['ProjectName', 'StartDate', 'EndDate'];
  @ViewChild(MatSort,null) sort: MatSort;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator,null) paginator: MatPaginator;
  searchKey: string;

  ngOnInit() {  
    this.refreshList();          
  }

  refreshList(){
    this.service.getProjectList().subscribe(data =>{    
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.listData.sort = this.sort;
      this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  } 
}
```

**project-list1.component.html**

```
  <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
```

**project.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectModel } from './project.model';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProjectService {
  formData  : ProjectModel;
  list : ProjectModel[];
  readonly rootURL ="http://localhost:65462/api"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postProject(formData : ProjectModel){
    console.log(formData);  
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Project',formData);     
   }

   getProjectList(): Observable<ProjectModel[]>{
     return this.http.get<ProjectModel[]>(this.rootURL+'/Project/');
   }

   refreshList(){
     return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/Project')
     .toPromise().then(res => this.list = res as ProjectModel[]);
    }

  }
```

Comment: too much code, can you share slackblitz url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an observable in your `project.service.ts` to make it easier to subscribe to changes. E.g.

```
export class ProjectService {
  formData  : ProjectModel;
-->  list$ : BehaviorSubject<ProjectModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  readonly rootURL ="http://localhost:65462/api"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  postProject(formData : ProjectModel){
    console.log(formData);  
    return this.http.post(this.rootURL+'/Project',formData);     
   }

   getProjectList(): Observable<ProjectModel[]>{
     return this.http.get<ProjectModel[]>(this.rootURL+'/Project/');
   }

   refreshList(){
     return this.http.get(this.rootURL+'/Project')
-->     .toPromise().then(res => this.list$.next(res));
    }

  }
```

Then you can subscribe to the listin the other component

```
  subscribeToList(){
    this.service.list$.subscribe(data =>{    
      this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.listData.sort = this.sort;
      this.listData.paginator = this.paginator;
    });
  }
```

You should also make sure to unsubscribe once this component is destroyed

Comment: Yes, this helped me with little modification. I need to call refreshList from service before I subscribe to list$. Worked Thanks.